# Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу по Питону

Tags: python

Условие:

Программа должна получать на вход шесть чисел: первые три - часы, минуты и секунды на часах в данный момент, остальные - часы, минуты и секунды, по прошествии которых нужно вывести время на часах.

Время выводится в формате h:mm:ss, то есть сначала записывается количество часов, потом двузначное количество минут, затем двузначное количество секунд. Количество минут и секунд при необходимости дополняются до двузначного числа нулями.

В этой задаче нельзя использовать условные операторы и операторы цикла; необходимо оставаться в рамках целочисленного типа данных и реализовывать решение с помощью арифметических операторов.

У меня не получается реализовать эту часть: Количество минут и секунд при необходимости дополняются до двузначного числа нулями.
код:

```
a = int(input("Введите кол-чо часов"))
b = int(input("Введите кол-чо минут"))
c = int(input("Введите кол-чо секунд"))
d = int(input("Введите сколько прошло часов"))
g = int(input("Введите сколько прошло минут"))
f = int(input("Введите сколько прошло секунд"))
summ1 = a+d
summ2 = b+g
summ3 = c+f
i = summ3 // 60
summ2 += i
summ3 = summ3 - (i * 60)
l = summ2 // 60
summ1 += l
summ2 = summ2 - (l * 60)
j = summ1 // 24
summ1 = summ1 - (j * 24)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сколько я понял, вам просят ПРИ ВЫВОДЕ записывать минуты и секунды обязательно двузначным числом. Причем целым. Делается это, например,  так:

```
summ2 = 3
print(f'{summ2:02}')
summ3 = 25
print(f'{summ3:02}')
```

Результат:

```
03
25
```

Надеюсь, встроить это в свой скрипт сумеете.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло